# Run-time error 6: Overflow: Excel VBA

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have been trying to resolve this but could not. I have the following VBA code. While running it gives "run time error 6: Overflow". I guess I have assigned a right type to each variable. Please help!!

```
Sub UseCoeff()
Dim a, b As Long
Dim Value1 As Double

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Activate
For b = 2 To 427
    For a = 2 To 431

        Value1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(a, b).Value / ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(432, b).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseCoeff").Cells(a, b).Value = Value1

    Next a
Next b
End Sub
```

Each cell will have a result that may be between 0 and 1 up to eight decimal places.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2003 you can't have 427 columns...

Answer (score 3):

If `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(432, b).Value` is ever 0, then `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(a, b).Value / ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(432, b).Value` will cause the Overflow error if `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(a, b).Value` is also 0.

To avoid this, use an if statement to filter out the 0s, just update the comment with the actual logic you want:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(432, b).Value = 0 Then
    Value1 = 'Whatever you want but probably 0.
Else
    Value1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(a, b).Value / ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA").Cells(432, b).Value
End If
```

Comment: Just did some testing and if I use a zero I get a `divide by zero` error opposed to overflow error.

Comment: @AlistairWeir Ah, I was slightly inaccurate. You get a `divide by zero` error if you divide anything that is not 0 by zero. You get an `overflow` error if you divide 0 by 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Dim a, b As Long`

a is not declared as a long it is declared as a variant try this:

```
Dim a as long, b as Long
```

**Edit:**
Having tested this, it still produces a Stack Overflow error. However it is good practice to declare your variables properly.

You also don't need this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

and if you declare `UseTableBEA` you can slim down your code:

```
Dim Ws1 as Worksheet
Set Ws1 = Sheets("UseTableBEA")
```

You can then use `Ws1` where you have previously used `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UseTableBEA")`